# Responding with 404 error code by API for valid request but no data found

Tags: http, get, http-status-code-404

We are designing an API for use by one of our apps and the API is supposed to return the next higher version given the version provided in the query string of the request. Something like this:

```
GET /update-available?AppVersion=3.2.3&someotherinfo=ABCD1234
```

The question is what should be the return code if there is no update available given a particular set of query params. (Eg., if the app already has the latest version).

Based on my limited knowledge and experience we should send a 200 with an empty response or message saying 'no update found'.

But one of my co-workers remarked that using 404 is better since 'update-available' is a question and the reply is 'not-found' and the appropriate response code.

Any help in deciding what is the more appropriate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best response status code is `204 No Content`, which means: "The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content" ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#cite_note-13))

The status code `200` is also appropriate, as it is the standard response for successful HTTP request -- the `/update-available` is a resource, a service, which processed pretty successful. The service result is "no update available", but the 
service itself exists, and works fine.

The status code `404` is NOT appropriate. The reason includes:

1. `4xx` status code means "Client Error". In this case, there is nothing wrong with the client.
2. `404` means "The requested resource could not be found but may be available in the future."([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#cite_note-13)). However, the requested resource (the service of whether update is avaiable) IS available.
3. If `404` is used in this "no update available" case, which status code should be used when `/update-available` route itself is unavailable (e.g. deleted from server configuration).